# How to add custom function in onClick-event jqGrid-mode editGridRow?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Firstly I used this call `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,pickdates);`, it worked fine with UI Datepicker integration, but editRow is implemented for inline editing, but I prefer modal dialog, so I switched to editGridRow, now I can't find the way to call my custom function (pickdates) in onClick-event. My current call is:

`jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow',id,{closeOnEscape:true,width:400,savekey:[true,13]});`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `dataInit` property of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) instead of the usage of `oneditfunc` parameter (`pickdates` in your case) of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) method.

```
editoptions: {
    dataInit : function (elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker();
    }
}
```

The setting is common for [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing), [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) and [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). Practically the same setting exist for the [searching configuration](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent methods calling the default function.

```
$('#grid').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    MyFunction();  // Here you can call your own function instead of the default one.

});
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can modify the code a little and make it work.

Comment: It is not realy what I am looking for. I try to to integrate UI Datepicker into editGridRow-mode.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit more ? I really did not understand clearly.

Comment: Take a look here jqGrid Demos

Comment: Take a look here http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, then jqGrid Demos>Integrations>UI Datepicker, you will find how to integrate Datepicker into editRow-mode. It works with jQuery('#rowed6').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,pickdates); But it doesnt work with editGridRow and I didnt find the possibility to integrate Datepicker in the editGridRow-mode.